# Check with PHP to see if XML is received completely

Tags: php, xml

An XML file is sent to me, using FTP, on a regular basis. Now, before processing it, I want to check if I received the entire file. So, to do this, I want to check if the closing tag is in the file.
Is there a way to do this using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

If you're processing it with an XML parser, it should tell you if the XML is invalid (e.g. if the whole file is not there).

You can also use an XSD schema to validate the format of the XML.

Comment: Exactly. Just parse it and you will know. As @Lix already said, the closing tags ( and lot's of other tags ) are optional in XML. The structure is only that matters.